# Necessary Read Frequency vs PPR of Rotary Encoder

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, encoder, accuracy, rotary

I am working on a microcontroller (ATMega328) project where I am planning to use a rotary encoder. I plan to have a non-time critical main loop and set up a timer interrupt to handle reading the encoder.

Is there any reference or rule of thumb for the frequency at which I would need the timer interrupt to be called (the read frequency) relative to the PPR of the encoder in order to have it be read accurately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this rotary encoder one with quadrature outputs?

Is this one connected to a fast motor or one that a user turns a simple knob?

If this is a quadrature encoder connected to a fast device please give up the idea of monitoring the encoder directly by sampling a couple of GPIO pins via a timer interrupt. Instead use an MCU that has timer/counter hardware specifically designed to capture and decode the quadrature waveforms.

On the other hand if the encoder is one of these low resolution user interface devices with a PPR count of say less than a hundred or so then it is feasible to design a timer driven interrupt sampling system that can monitor the quadrature inputs on a pair of port pins. Keep in mind that the these low cost types of rotary encoders often use wiper contacts inside that will require de-bouncing similar to regular switch contacts. This will eat into the maximum speed with which you can decode and count the quadrature pulses.

I have been successful with using a 1msec timer interrupt state machine to decode decode user interface encoders with 32 and 64 PPR including debouncing. Of course if it is a non-detented freely rotated device it may still be possible to get the quadrature signals coming in faster than a 1KHz interrupt can keep up if the user happened to give the knob or shaft a very fast spin.

Comment: I am using the encoder as a user interface device. PPR is below 100.

Comment: How would software debouncing for a quadrature circuit work? Should I same at a higher rate and only accept a value if it is sustained for a certain period of time?

Comment: I have used a sampling filter on the Chan-A and Chan-B separately. The filter would function such that you do not accept the new level of the signal until it has been detected at the same level for a certain number of times. Often this can be done by keeping the bit levels of the pins in what amounts to software shift registers. Lets say you choose a 1msec sample rate and uses a byte variable for the "shift register" for each of the inputs. At each sample period you shift the current port bit into the byte while shifting all the previous samples over. After the each shift (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) is complete you can examine the the byte for being 0x00 or 0xFF to note the current stable state of the debounced input. This described scenario would give you an 8 msec debounce period tolerance. You can adjust the period by either changing the timer interrupt period or adding or taking away the number of bits you manage in the "shift register". Evaluate the raw encoder outputs on a scope to determine how much debounce time is actually needed. The debounced Chan-A and Chan-B signals become the ones you use to detect the quadrature signalling (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) pulse count, rate or direction as needed for your user interface.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on two things: the encoder resolution and the maximum rotation rate. Let's say you have an encoder which puts out 1024 ppr, and has a maximum rotation rate of 5 rps (300 rpm). Then the minimum response time must be $$t = \frac{1}{5\times 1024} = 195 \mu\text{sec} $$ Note that shaft rate is instantaneous rotational velocity, and does not imply that the shaft will complete 5 revolutions in one second.

Comment: Interesting choice of rate. I had to observe an infusion pump motor cam position while at the same time monitoring quadrature pulses (and home pulse) at \$10-20(+)\:\mu\textrm{s}\$ intervals (width varies a little from pulse to pulse) for a cam angle calibration test stand I was working on. This was for 10k pulses per rev at 300 RPM. The motor had to be validated at a variety of speeds for proper calibration, before the final binding epoxy was added to make it permanent. Even at these rates, this was not at all even close to the more difficult parts of this medical, life critical application.